# GNU Radio Companion FFT Window

Tags: window, fft, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have a data file that I am trying to run through the GNU Radio Companion FFT Sink.

I have my flow graph set up, no problem there. However, the FFT plot is mostly negative, and the window starts out set to 0->100. I can hit "Autoscale", but my data is only about 15 seconds, and I would like to be able to see all of it from the beginning. Is there a way to set the FFT window to display all the data? Is there some way to make the data show up in the default FFT window? Any other possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your FFT plot is negative because the scale is in dB (decibel).